# How to write a copy constructor for Template Class - C++

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

In my header file I have

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
    public:
         // constructor and other things

         const Vector& operator=(const Vector &rhs);   
};
```

and here is one declaration which I've tried so far

```
template <typename T> Vector& Vector< T >::operator=( const Vector &rhs )
{
    if( this != &rhs )
    {
        delete [ ] array;
        theSize = rhs.size();
        theCapacity = rhs.capacity();

        array = new T[ capacity() ];
        for( int i = 0; i < size(); i++ ){
            array[ i ] = rhs.array[ i ];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

this is what the compiler is telling me

```
In file included from Vector.h:96,
                 from main.cpp:2:
Vector.cpp:18: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token
make: *** [project1] Error 1
```

How do I properly declare the copy constructor?

Note: This is for a project and I cannot change the header declaration, so suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892942/c-template-class-copy-constructor-and-assignment-operator), while useful, are not helpful in this particular instance.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE: You declare an assignment operator, not copy constructor*

1. You missed the `const` qualifier before return type
2. You missed the template argument(`<T>`) for return type and function argument

Use this:

```
template <typename T>
const Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T>& rhs)
```

Comment: The `<T>` is not required for the function argument, since that comes after the member name `operator=`, and the injected class name is then in scope.  Likewise, you could also do `template <typename T> auto Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& rhs) -> Vector&`